# Validation using validation service

Tags: validation, angular

I have partly model-driven partly template-driven form and I want to validate one of the inputs using custom logic. The problem is, control is in invalid state even validation returns as valid. What am I doing wrong?

```
<span *ngIf="identityNumber.touched && !identityNumber.valid">invalid</span>
```

..

```
this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
  identityNumber: ['', Validators.required, 
      ValidationService.validateIdentityNumber]
});
```

..

```
public static validateIdentityNumber(control: Control) {
  let val: string = <string>control.value;
  if (val && val.length == 11) {
    return null;
  } else {
    return { "invalidIdentityNumber": true };
  }
}
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/1IY4iXEeQDXUanCOSCKX?p=preview

It displays as "invalid" even when you type 11 characters.

(I know there's a length validator, this is for sample's sake)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to pass more than one validator use `Validators.compose`

```
identityNumber: ['', 
    Validators.compose([
        Validators.required, 
        ValidationService.validateIdentityNumber
    ])
]
```

(the 3rd parameter is for async validators)